# Uber API calls are getting HTTP 401 response code

Tags: api, uber-api

Uber API calls are getting HTTP 401 response code.

https://api.uber.com/v1.2/products?latitude=11.111111&longitude=-11.111111

Our Uber API calls are getting HTTP 401 response code and we have already submitted the form as per Uber's email "Uber API Policy Updates" to continue API access for our app. They stopped working today, 6/21/2019. Why?

https://api.uber.com/v1.2/products?latitude=11.111111&longitude=-11.111111

List of Uber products.

Comment: We are getting the same error. Starting today, we are unable to successfully connect to Uber API and get an OAuth “invalid scope” error. On the developer dashboard, the app is still there, but the “scopes” fields are blank and we cannot select any scopes where previously we selected “profile”. Any clues on how to fix this issue?